# How to import db-sample-schemas into Oracle's DB?

Tags: import, dump, oracle-18c

I need to import some sample dump file for educational and testing purposes. I've found the [next](https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas/blob/master/order_entry/PurchaseOrders.dmp) dump file and tried to import it using:

```
imp testuser/oracle file=/home/oracle/PurchaseOrders.dmp
```

> ```
> Connected to: Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
> Version 18.3.0.0.0
>
> IMP-00037: Character set marker unknown
> IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
> ```

Also, I've tried to import it using:

```
impdp testuser/oracle directory=dmp_dir dumpfile=PurchaseOrders.dmp full=y;
```

> ```
> Connected to: Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
> ORA-39001: invalid argument value
> ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
> ORA-31619: invalid dump file "/home/oracle/PurchaseOrders.dmp"
> ```

How could I import this dump into my test Oracle DB?

Thank you!

Comment: from error logs you have posted, you need to get a valid dump file because the one you seems corrupted.

Comment: This dump could be viewed by text file viewer/reader. So, maybe someone could say what is wrong with it. Or, maybe there's another tool could be used to import it. I'm still looking for correct sample dump file.

Comment: And I've posted two error logs and they are different. `impdp` says it is invalid, but `imp` says about Character set marker. These two are different commands.

Comment: Just clone or download whole folder db_samples_schema(8 Schemas) and follow the instructions outlined in first page Metadata is created with sql scripts inside corresponding schemas.If you wanted to install only OE schema,download order_entry folder and start with oe_main.sql in order_entry folder(comment out anything related to HR schema) but before starting the script run the perl command that replaces `__SUB__CWD__` with

Comment: I was unable to edit my last comment perl script replaces above strings to current working direrctory.That dumpfile is readable text file not a valid data pump file

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to deploy all schemas.